# Jquery toggleClass img url after click not working

Tags: jquery

So my function isn't working. I don't know how to solve it, is images from url even working with toggleClass? I was searching for the answer but i cant find for this one.

```
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="games">
      <ul>
        <li><a title=""><img src="https://icon-library.net//images/grand-theft-auto-v-icon/grand-theft-auto-v-icon-5.jpg" width="50" /></a></li>
        <li><a class=""><img src="https://styles.redditmedia.com/t5_2rn7o/styles/communityIcon_2083me9o3ia21.png" width="50" alt=""></a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <img id="btn" class="button" src="eeeee.png"/>
  </div>
```

```
.button{
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 18em;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;

}
.button:hover{
    filter: grayscale(100%) sepia(41%) brightness(200%) saturate(0%) contrast(1000%);
}
```

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#btn').attr('src', 'eee.png');
});
```

Comment: Note that your HTML is invalid. You can't have a div as a child element of the `<ul>`

Comment: ive already change that

Comment: Please edit your question and correct the invalid HTML there...so we can see it too ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what are you really trying to do but i think you don't really want to change class of your image to change the picture itself since it cannot effect the source attribute.

when using jquery as it seems you do, you can change image source attribute like

```js
$("#your_image").attr("src","source_of_image.jpg");
```

Comment: what i exactly want is create function, when i just clicking this button (i have my icon, so i don't have different way to display that as a button but by content: ) and when i click this button it changes to a different image

Comment: i dont know* 
it's something like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFf56HOxOC0 there but instead of already made icons i have my custom one